# count occurrence of character

Tags: linux, shell, command-line

I have a .txt file

```
ID Number        Name                         Fed Sex Tit  Wtit
4564             A B M Yusop, Tapan           BAN M
59841212         A Rafiq                      IND F   WFM  WFM
19892            Aadel F , Arvin              IND M 
.
.
.
```

And I have to count in linux command line how many female  F and male M are in this file. 
I´m new to linux shell so I only think about `grep` command but there can be "M" and "F" also in "Name".

Any advice?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use awk to do this (both find the column, and take the counts):

```
$ awk '
# first line
NR == 1 { 
    if (col = index($0, "Sex")) {
        next # skip rest of script for this line
    }

    print "Could not find the required header"
    exit
} 

# all lines
{ 
    # increment counts of each `M` or `F`
    ++count[substr($0, col, 1)]
} 

END { 
    # loop through count array and print
    for (i in count) print i, count[i] 
}' file
```

Comment: You might want to use `index()` instead of `match()`, but +1

Comment: @glennjackman absolutely, no need for `match` here, will edit, thanks!

Comment: @TomFenech Thank you for your answer. But one little question. What the $0 means in this index function? I only know that $something is positional parametr and $0 is command name.

Comment: @Martina this is inside an awk script, so `$0` means the whole line: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Fields.html

Answer (score -1):

First use `cut` to get just the one column.  Something like:

```
cut -c40 < file.txt # gets the 40th character on each line
```

Then count the distinct values:

```
cut -c40 < file.txt | sort | uniq -c
```

Comment: thanks. And how can I find out on which position the "Sex" is to use -c40?

Comment: @MartinaZapletalová: I'd open the file in a text editor like Emacs and ask the editor which column it is.  Or just count with your keyboard.  Or guess and check.  Or....

Comment: So there isn´t a way how to do it in command line?

Comment: I have to do it all in command line. But ok, I tried to count with keyboard - it´s 81th char. But when I tried your command `cut -c81 < myfilename.txt | sort | uniq -c` it didn´t do anything. And when I used only `cut -c81 < myfilename.txt  it really print only M, F and S (first letter from "Sex")

Comment: @MartinaZapletalová: If `cut -c81 < myfilename.txt` gives you a bunch of lines with one character like `S\nM\nF\nM`, then piping it to `sort` will sort them, and `uniq -c` will print the counts.  For example run `(echo S; echo M; echo F; echo M) | sort | uniq -c` and see that it prints the counts of each character.  It does not "do nothing."

Answer (score -1):

In bash with GNU grep, you could write:

```
IFS= read -r header < file          # read the first line of the file
prefix=${header%%Sex *}             # remove "Sex " and everthing after it
skip_regex=${prefix//?/.}           # replace all chars with "."

# then find the letters and count them
grep -oP "^$skip_regex\\K[MF]" file | sort | uniq -c
```

outputs

```
  1 F
  2 M
```